# Angular 7 - Abrir componente que está importado em outro módulo

Tags: angular, typescript, router

Estou com uma dúvida de como chamar um componente que está importado em outro módulo.

A situação é a seguinte:
Tenho o componente perfil, onde listo os perfis da empresa.
Cada perfil te as suas permissões no sistema.
Nessa lista, tem um botão onde o adm clica para adicionar as permissões para aquele perfil, esse botão funciona como um atalho.
Esse atalho leva para um outro componente chamado "PerfilPermissoes".

No componente perfil permissoes, tenho um componente chamado perfil-permissoes-form, onde adiciono as permissões para aquele perfil.

Estou usando o routerLink, no momento, eu só consegui criando um outro form.

Código abaixo:
1- routerLink "add"

```html
<h4 class="m-3"> Perfil</h4>
<nav class="nav">
    <a class="btn btn-success m-3" [routerLink]="['new']">Criar Perfil</a>
</nav>
<table class="table table-light mx-3 text-secondary">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nome do Perfil</th>
      <th>Setor</th>
      <th>Sistema</th>
      <th>Descrição</th>
      <th>Ações</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr *ngFor="let p of perfil">
      <th>{{ p.id_perfil }}</th>
      <th>{{ p.nome_perfil }}</th>
      <th>{{ p.nome_setor }}</th>
      <th>{{ p.nome_sistema }}</th>
      <th>{{ p.descricao }}</th>
      <th><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info mr-2" [routerLink]="[p.id_perfil, 'edit']">Editar</a>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2" [routerLink]="[p.id_perfil, 'add']">Acrescentar Permissões</a>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="onDelete(p.id_perfil)">Deletar</button>
      </th>

    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<ng-template #deleteModal>
  <div class="modal-body text-center">
    <p>Tem certeza que quer deletar?</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="onConfirmDelete()">Sim</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onDeclineDelete()">Não</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

2- routing-module com o path pro novo form

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PerfilComponent } from './perfil.component';
import { PerfilFormComponent } from './perfil-form/perfil-form.component';
import { PerfilPermissoesPicklistComponent } from '../perfil-permissoes/perfil-permissoes-picklist/perfil-permissoes-picklist.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PerfilComponent },
  { path: 'new', component: PerfilFormComponent },
  { path: ':id/edit', component: PerfilFormComponent },
  { path: ':id/add', component: PerfilPermissoesPicklistComponent },


];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PerfilRoutingModule { }
```

Alguem saberia usar algo parecido com redirect ou algo similar para abrir outro componente já declarado em outro module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exprimente assim

```
 {path: 'RouteName', loadChildren: () => NomeModulo}
```

Comment: Opa, fiz esse comando e meu o seguinte erro:
"Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component PerfilPermissoesComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
Error: Component PerfilPermissoesComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module."

Comment: Eu fiz uma pesquisa, e nela diz algo parecido com o que você disse, de importa o modulo para dentro de outro modulo, mas não consegui fazer funcionar ainda. Se tiver um exemplo facilitaria a vida.

Comment: Eu tentei importar o modulo para dentro de outro modulo, até funcionou, só que vou ter que editar o caminho nos path, pois são todos parecidos por padrão (/new, /:id/edit, ...)

Comment: nao consegue por no modulo do ficheiro dessas rotas o modulo que quer usar? (na secçao dos imports) @EdwardRamos

Comment: e depois tem de por o import no seu ficheiro de rotas